# How to stop mining unwanted blocks on private net on geth ethrereum

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I have started a geth client using the below client(I had already created two accounts.:

```
geth --datadir datadir --networkid 123 --rpc --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpccorsdomain="*" --unlock <my account> --minerthreads="1" --maxpeers=0 --mine console
```

I opened the the ethereum wallet and deployed the smart contract from there. The transactionId and the contract address is received on my geth console.

Then I started my Dapp and created the instances of the contract and I am calling the contract invoking a contract function through web3 API. The contract function gets invoked but the transaction does not get submitted in the block unless I start mining. Hence I started miner.start() This started mining numerous blocks.

My question is where are these blocks coming from if I have my own private net and have submitted only one transaction. This is adding too many blocks and my blocksize is increasing unnecessarily. How to mine only the transaction I have submitted?

Answer (score 1):

These blocks are mined by your client by using `miner.start()` the blocks are mined until your transaction got included in one of these blocks. To stop the operation tape `miner.stop()` even the log didn't give you the prompt. However, the best thing is using 
a script that mine only the pending transactions (you mine only few blocks until your transaction got mined).

such script will contain

```
var mining_threads = 1

    function checkWork() {
        if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) {
            if (eth.mining) return;
            console.log("== Pending transactions! Mining...");
            miner.start(mining_threads);
        } else {
            miner.stop();
            console.log("== No transactions! Mining stopped.");
        }
    }
    console.log("checkWork() is defined");
    eth.filter("latest", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });
    eth.filter("pending", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });

    checkWork();
```

on geth use

```
 loadScript("C:/Users/Tera_pc/Desktop/demo/mine_pending.js")
```

Comment: Do I have to loadscript() for each transaction?

Comment: I tried this; now the mining is taking too long time; I am not sure why it is so; I have develeoped a Dapp based on cryptocurrency ethereum example. when i am transferring the token to another account it is taking too long a time to get mined now. :( . Is this because the block size has increased? Currently the block size is 97.

Comment: this doesn't have any relation with the block size, you need only to wait few seconds until your transaction got mined, you could instead using previous script use : miner.start(8); admin.sleepBlocks(10); miner.stop() ; you precise how many block to mine